# I am using %matplotlib widget, but it is not printing plots in the output

Tags: python, matplotlib

I trying to use interactive plots in Jupyterlab as below. Am I making a mistake here? Because I cannot see the plots and am getting output as mentioned below. Only %matplotlib inline seems to work, but I do not like it as changing these plots is a pain. Can someone help me run either the matplotlib widget or any other easy way of plotting in Jupyterlab. I am really struggling to get good plots for many days.
 Please help.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
%matplotlib widget
scatter(1,5)
```

Canvas(toolbar=Toolbar(toolitems=[('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'), ('Back', 'Back to previous …
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x28ed8195c88>
my versions are: matplotlib: 3.1.1, Python 3.7.4, IPython 7.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Just pip install ipympl.

It works now after running the following bash commands.

```
conda install -y nodejs
pip install --upgrade jupyterlab
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
jupyter labextension install jupyter-matplotlib
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Must restart jupyter server after running these commands

PS. - restarting kernel does not work. only when you restart jupyter lab from terminal it works.

Comment: still same issue:  Canvas(toolbar=Toolbar(toolitems=[('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'), ('Back', 'Back to previous …
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x1b0ef920b48>